# interact with newly created html via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I would like to add a new div from javascript to my existing html page. Normally I do this with the instruction document.createElement("div") and I fill this div with the methode div.innerHTML = "" (for example). This works fine in most cases, but now I would like to add a selectionlist to my div and fill this lists with some data. This method doesn't work:

```
function initEdit(){
     addPanel = document.createElement("div");
     addPanel.innerHTML = "<form id='addProperty' method='get'> <table>" +
                                "<tr> <td> <select size='4' style='width:140px; height:200px' id='object_property_selection' onClick='unSelect(\"data_property_selection\")'> </td>" +
                                     "<td> <select size='4' style='width:140px; height:200px' id='object_selection'>" +
                                          "<textarea style='width:140px; height:200px; display:none' id='data_selection' /> </td> </tr>" +
                                "<tr> <td> <select size='4' style='width:140px; height:100px' id='data_property_selection' onClick='unSelect(\"object_property_selection\")'> </td>" +
                                     "<td> </td> </tr>" +
                                "<tr> <td colspan=2> <input type='button' name='Submit' style='width:100%' onClick='submitProperty()' /> </td> </tr>" +
                            "</table> </form>";

    $('body').jAlert(contents, 'info', offset);
    list1.forEach(function(element, id){
        var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        option.text = option.value = property;
        form.data_property_selection.options.add(element);
    })
}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? (BTW: I can't set this html code in the page at the beginning, because this is the contents of a [jAlert](http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/02/22/jalert-jquery-alert-box-plugin/) div)

**update: solution**

```
properties1.concat(properties2).forEach(function(property, id){
    if (id < object_properties.length) propertyList1 += "<option value='" + property + "'>" + property + "</option>";
    else propertyList2 += "<option value='" + property + "'>" + property + "</option>";
})
objects.forEach(function(feature, id) {
    objectList += "<option value='" + feature._id + "'>" + feature.name + "</option>";
})

propertyList = "<form id='addProperty' method='get'> <table>" +
                            "<tr> <td> <select size='4' style='width:140px; height:200px' id='object_property_selection' onClick='unSelect(\"data_property_selection\")'>" +
                                       propertyList1 + "</select> </td>" +
                                 "<td> <select size='4' style='width:140px; height:200px' id='object_selection'>" +
                                       objectList + "</select> </td>" +
                                      "<textarea style='width:140px; height:200px; display:none' id='data_selection' /> </td> </tr>" +
                            "<tr> <td> <select size='4' style='width:140px; height:100px' id='data_property_selection' onClick='unSelect(\"object_property_selection\")'>" +
                                       propertyList2 + "</select> </td>" +
                                 "<td> </td> </tr>" +
                            "<tr> <td colspan=2> <input type='button' name='Submit' style='width:100%' onClick='submitProperty()' /> </td> </tr>" +
                        "</table> </form>";
```

Comment: You don't seem to actually add the created div to the page. Don't you need document.body.appendChild(addPanel) somewhere?

Comment: I updated the post: It was the wrong version of the code. The contents is used by the jAlert

Comment: try to look into jQuery delegate function, which allows for access to js generated DOM

Comment: your code seems vague, could you create a simple demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, achieving what you want with this method is impossible. Instead of using `innerHTML`, you should do the long way, creating all the inner tags with createElement as well, and appending them as children. Using jQuery can make this job *a lot* easier.

Here is an example of how to do it with jQuery: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-dom.htm), and the [official API](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Alternatively, if you can first create the inner list, then just create it and concatenate it as a string as a part of `innerHTML` (first make the list, only then edit `innerHTML`).

Comment: thank you for the advice, to speed things up, I went with the second solution (I added my solution at the end of the question)